# test returning value of a method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Let's say I have a dummy presenter class for my dummy model like this:

```
class DummyPresenter
  def initialize(dummy_id)
    @dummy = DummyModel.find(dummy_id)
  end

  def id
    @dummy.id
  end

  def change_child_dummy_name(child_dummy_id, new_child_dummy_name)
    child_dummy = @dummy.child_dummies.find(child_dummy_id)
    child_dummy.update_attributes(:display_name => new_child_dummy_name)
    child_dummy # I need to return a child_dummy object here!!
  end
end
```

In my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DummyPresenter do
  before :all do
    @dummy_presenter = DummyPresenter.new(1)
    @child_dummy = DummyModel.find(1).child_dummies.first
  end

  it 'should update the display name of a child dummy for a dummy' do
    expect(@child_dummy.display_name).to be_nil

    @dummy_presenter.change_child_dummy_name(@child_dummy.id, 'Child Dummy network')
    @child_dummy.reload
    expect(@child_dummy.display_name).to eq('Child Dummy network')
  end

  it 'should return updated child dummy' do
    child_dummy_id = @child_dummy.id
    @dummy_presenter.should_receive(:change_child_dummy_name).at_least(:once).with(child_dummy_id, 'Child Dummy network').and_return(@child_dummy)
    @dummy_presenter.change_child_dummy_name(child_dummy_id, 'Child Dummy network')
  end
end
```

Above test cases pass without any issue.

Now, as per my understanding the first `it` block works perfectly fine where I just see the updated attribute. But, the second block where I expect the method: `change_child_dummy_name` to return `@child_dummy` doesn't work or maybe I didn't understand the code I've written here properly. Because, when I change `change_child_dummy_name` method inside presenter to this:

```
def change_child_dummy_name(child_dummy_id, new_child_dummy_name)
  child_dummy = @dummy.child_dummies.find(child_dummy_id)
  child_dummy.update_attributes(:display_name => new_child_dummy_name)
  "child_dummy" # A String!! Where as I need to return a child_dummy object here!!
end
```

The specs again pass without raising any error. So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the essence of this question is here

```
@dummy_presenter.should_receive(:change_child_dummy_name).at_least(:once).with(child_dummy_id, 'Child Dummy network').and_return(@child_dummy)
```

`should_receive` actually **stubs** the method's result.

if `and_returns` is used, its operand is the new value, if not the stubbed value is `nil`.

In your case that is the `@child_dummy` object. Which by the way is the reason your test passed the first time as well!

One way to bypass this behavior is to use `.and_call_original` which will do what you expect.

You should rewrite it as two tests:

- one that tests that `change_child_dummy_name` is called (maybe it is not necessairy)
- one that will test that the desired attributes of `@child_dummy` (because the object you create in your rspec test will not be the same that the method will return).

Comment: Yes, `@dummy_presenter.should_receive(:change_child_dummy_name).at_least(:once).with(child_dummy_id, 'Child Dummy network').and_return(@child_dummy)` is what I'm after. I already have written the first point you've mentioned in first block, correct me if I'm wrong? So, what you're suggesting is to call `change_child_dummy_name` and store the value in an object and check with `@child_dummy.reload` to verify this?

Comment: the point is that `should_receive` also **stubs**. What you can check for is that the returned object is of a certain class, or has certain attributes, but NOT that it is the same object.

Comment: `and_call_original` worked just as I thought. Also, I needed to see the object to be `@child_object`. I don't have to worry about the exact match since, I've already checked the attribute in the first spec. Anyways, thanks for your time. :)